# @Value annotation type casting to Integer from String

Tags: java, spring, casting, annotations, property-placeholder

I'm trying to cast the output of a value to an integer:

```
@Value("${api.orders.pingFrequency}")
private Integer pingFrequency;
```

The above throws the error

```
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
    Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
    For input string: "(java.lang.Integer)${api.orders.pingFrequency}"
```

I've also tried `@Value("(java.lang.Integer)${api.orders.pingFrequency}")`

Google doesn't appear to say much on the subject.  I'd like to always be dealing with an integer instead of having to parse this value everywhere it's used.

**Workaround**

I realize a workaround may be to use a setter method to run the conversion for me, but if Spring can do it I'd rather learn something about Spring.

Comment: Is the exception for the first try or the second?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The first

Comment: If you ever come across such a problem, it's most obviously, that you forgot to define the right PropertySource. You'll need:
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

Comment: it can also be caused by improper encoding of properties files (java expects ISO 8859-1)

Comment: Missing curly brace on end of property place holder caused this error for me :/

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Assuming you have a properties file on your classpath that contains

```
api.orders.pingFrequency=4
```

I tried inside a `@Controller`

```
@Controller
public class MyController {     
    @Value("${api.orders.pingFrequency}")
    private Integer pingFrequency;
    ...
}
```

With my servlet context containing :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myprops.properties" />
```

It worked perfectly.

So either your property is not an integer type, you don't have the property placeholder configured correctly, or you are using the wrong property key.

I tried running with an invalid property value, `4123;`. The exception I got is

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4123;"
```

which makes me think the value of your property is

```
api.orders.pingFrequency=(java.lang.Integer)${api.orders.pingFrequency}
```

Answer (score 41):

I was looking for the answer on internet and I found the following

```
@Value("#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('${aDateFormat}').parse('${aDateStr}')}")
Date myDate;
```

So in your case you could try with this

```
@Value("#{new Integer('${api.orders.pingFrequency}')}")
private Integer pingFrequency;
```

Comment: This gives me SpelEvaluationException. Are you sure it works?

Comment: I am also getting SpelEvaluationException

Comment: Instead of 'new Integer.parseInt' using 'new Integer'  worked for me.

Comment: I am getting   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: &quot;${redis.server.port}&quot

Comment: Make sure you are not leaving out the $ @Value("${api.orders.pingFrequency}") should work just fine

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same situation. It was caused by not having a [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) in the Spring context, which resolves values against the `@Value` annotation inside of classes.

Include a property placeholder to solve the problem, no need to use Spring expressions for integers (the property file does not have to exist if you use `ignore-resource-not-found="true"`):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/path/to/my/app.properties"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to convert a **property** to an **integer** from properties file there are **2** solutions which I found:

Given scenario: **customer.properties** contains **customer.id = 100** as a field and you want to access it in spring configuration file as **integer**.The property **customerId** is declared as type **int** in the Bean **Customer**

Solution 1:

```html
<property name="customerId" value="#{T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt('${customer.id}')}" />
```

In the above line, the **string** value from properties file is converted to **int** type.

solution 2: Use some other extension inplace of **propeties**.For Ex.- If your properties file name is 
            **customer.properties** then make it **customer.details** and in the configuration file use the below code

```html
<property name="customerId"   value="${customer.id}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using @Configuation then instantiate below static bean. If not static @Configutation is instantiated very early and and the BeanPostProcessors responsible for resolving annotations like @Value, @Autowired etc, cannot act on it. Refer [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-bean-and-propertyplaceholderconfigurer.html)

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
   return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Comment: To add to the above, given that the property configurer `@Bean` would only appear in one configuration class, care should be taken when deleting any configuration class from your codebase, which could inadvertently remove this bean.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I solved using this. Refer this [Spring MVC: @Value annotation to get int value defined in *.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957364/spring-mvc-value-annotation-to-get-int-value-defined-in-properties-file)

```
@Value(#{propertyfileId.propertyName})
```

works

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work. #{...} gives me compile error. Instead, you could use int and not Integer...

Answer (score 1):

when use @Value, you should add @PropertySource annotation on Class, or specify properties holder in spring's xml file.
eg.

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class BusinessClass{
   @Value("${user.name}")
   private String name;
   @Value("${user.age}")
   private int age;
   @Value("${user.registed:false}")
   private boolean registed;
}
```

config.properties

```
user.name=test
user.age=20
user.registed=true
```

this works!

Of course, you can use placeholder xml configuration instead of annotation.
spring.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs when you have 2 resources with the same file name; say "configurations.properties" within 2 different jar or directory path configured within the classpath. For example:

You have your "configurations.properties" in your process or web application (jar, war or ear). But another dependency (jar) have the same file "configurations.properties" in the same path. Then I suppose that Spring have no idea (@_@?) where to get the property and just sends the property name declared within the @Value annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my POST request was sent to the same url as GET (with get parameters using "?..=..") and that parameters had the same name as form parameters. Probably Spring is merging them into an array and parsing was throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Since using the **@Value("new Long("myconfig")")** with cast could **throw error** on **startup** if the **config is not found** or if not in the same expected **number format**

We used the following approach and is working as expected with fail safe check.

```
@Configuration()
public class MyConfiguration {

   Long DEFAULT_MAX_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 5l;

   @Value("db.timeoutInString")
   private String timeout;

   public Long getTimout() {
        final Long timoutVal = StringUtil.parseLong(timeout);
        if (null == timoutVal) {
            return DEFAULT_MAX_IDLE_TIMEOUT;
        }
        return timoutVal;
    }
}
```