# How to pass varaible to test which annotate @Value

Tags: spring, unit-testing

i have service like :

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
...
private Integer days;

//constructor
public UserServiceImpl(@Value("${test.days}") Integer days,
                              .....)
}
```

I pass varable from applicatin.yml and when i run my project it works fine.
But when i run my tests i get exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ServiceImpl#0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 11; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${test.days}"
```

seems like it cant see my value from application.yml and trying to wrap string "${test.days}" to Integer...how to avoid this ?

Comment: Did you tried creating an application.yml file in test/resources folder and adding property to it?

Answer (score 0):

above of private Integer days; you can put @Value and the name of the property in application.properties and in your methods of your class use days property directly

Comment: dont work, i have tryed

Comment: could you post your code

Answer (score 0):

Looks lile its impossible for me, so i made Configuration class and mock it in test.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62871732/10358410
I want to emphasize that when you run the application, everything works fine, the problem is only in the tests.