# Spring: How to inject Integer and long values from configuration file in annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm struggling to use the configuration variables in the spring project to inject values other than String in the annotations. Is there a way to inject them?
The annotations require Integer and long values, but when injecting from application.yml, it is considered as String.

See the example below:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = "${scheduler.fixedrate:10}")
public void init(){}
```

The error is:

> Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'long'

Any solution?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394872/8681) answer your question?

Comment: @Jorn, No, the Value annotation does the cast itself.

Comment: Wait, is the type of the annotation value `fixedRate` a `long` itself? Then this is never going to work. You cannot use a Spring property to provide that value.

Comment: exactly. The field is long. I'm looking for a solution to it. There should be a solution. It doesn't make sense that this feature is only implemented for String values!!

Comment: What doesn't make sense is trying to assign a `String` to a `long` and expecting Spring to magically fix it.

Comment: I'm not expecting to Spring fix it. I'm looking for a solution. If you have a solution for it, I will give you a bounty.

Comment: I already gave you the answer. Refusing to accept it won't help anyone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255590/discussion-between-hamed-and-jorn).

Comment: You cannot, there is no work around. Period. There is nothing that Spring can do as it simply isn't allowed by the Java specification. Values in annotations need to be constants (i.e. not dynamic as in your case). Which is the reason why there is the `fixedRateString` which allows a String and thus an expression which is resolved at runtime. However this is a Spring solution. For annotations that don't have a workaround like this there is simply no solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution, simply because the specification doesn't allow it. In short that is how annotations work. The values for attributes have to adhere to the type they are defined in, and a `String` isn't a `long`.

The value substition is a Spring feature and which is why for certain annotations there is also a `*String` parameter to work around this. Which is why the `@Scheduled` has the `fixedRateString` property to work around this. It is a `String` and the `String` is parsed by Spring as an expression and thus you can resolve the value **at runtime** to the value you want to use.

This all is build into Spring for annotations that are created by Spring, it will **not work** for annotations not under the control of Spring or simply for values that aren't of type `String`.

So the basic answer to your question is there is no solution! Not the answer you wanted to hear but the answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why it is not possible we need to understand how and what Spring does when you do something like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${scheduler.fixedrate:10}")
public void init(){}
```

The string `${scheduler.fixedrate:10}` was assigned to `fixedRateString` and won't get replaced by the value in your application.yml. You maybe thought `fixedRateString` would get the actual value from your application.yml which is not the case, it simply gets the value you configured.

Now when your application starts, Spring will interpret this string and then resolves it to your value in the application.yml and use it to setup scheduling, so this replacement happens at runtime and NOT at compile-time, this is the key point.

You wrote *There should be a solution. It doesn't make sense that this feature is only implemented for String values.* which is not entirely correct. It is not tied to string values, just the key of the property you define in the annotation is a string but the actual value of the property can be of any type.

**Preprocessors**
What you probably want is a preprocessor which processes the source files before they get compiled (like C has one). But Java has no such preprocessor. Furthermore, it would not be possible for Spring, to implement such a preprocessor if Java would provide such a possibilty. The reason is, that values of properties are determined at runtime, as the application.yml is not the only place where one can configure properties. So event if Java would support preprocessors, there is no way to replace the key with the actual value as the value cannot be determined at compile time.

Comment: So `Strings` are not compile time constraints? and we can't define Integer and long in application.yml?

Comment: Strings are compile time constant. But they get resolved at runtime by spring, the resolved value could also be an integer or a long. What you want is something like a preprocessor, which replaces the string by the actual value before the code gets compiled but such a preprocessor does not exist and is also not possible, as the actual value cannot be determined during compile time as values for a property might be supplied during runtime.

Comment: I edited my comment and tried to explain what Spring actually does which might help to understand why its not possible what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Scheduled` annotation also has a `fixedRateString` property:

```
    /**
     * Execute the annotated method with a fixed period between invocations.
     * <p>The time unit is milliseconds by default but can be overridden via
     * {@link #timeUnit}.
     * @return the period as a String value &mdash; for example, a placeholder
     * or a {@link java.time.Duration#parse java.time.Duration} compliant value
     * @since 3.2.2
     */
    String fixedRateString() default "";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my point is how to use variables from the application.yml as integer and long. The `Scheduled` annotation is an example.